# Algorithm to convert a 2d voxel map to line sometimes gets stuck

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, line

I have a 2D voxel map for a game, which is a 2D array where 1 means ground and 0 means sky.

Example: all 1's in the array (ground) are green boxes
[image: 2d voxel map, red is start coordinate]

The algorithm starts at the leftmost ground voxel that touches the sky (red box in picture).

It will explore 8 neighbours of the current position to check if one of them is a ground voxel and also touches a sky voxel. This means it should be added to the groundline.

Example of the algorithm working (it's able to go in 'caves' too)
[image]

On this map it figured it out and returned a line across the ground.

In some situations it suddenly stops though, like on this map: 
[image: failed algorithm]

After about 10 loops it stopped creating the line.

Here's the code, with some explanatory comments in there:

```
voxelToLine() {
let voxels = this.voxels.length,//this.voxels is the 2d array
    lineGround = [],
    checkedVoxels = [],
    nowChecking,
    toCheck = [],
    otherPaths = [],
    done = false;

for (let y = 1; y < voxels - 1; y++)//sets first coordinate for line
    if (this.voxels[0][y] && (!this.voxels[0][y - 1] || !this.voxels[1][y] || !this.voxels[0][y + 1])) {
        lineGround[0] = [0, y / voxels];
        nowChecking = [1, y];//search starts from this point
    }

let looped = 0;
while (!done) {//continues search untill right side is located, or it got stuk (max 10*voxelmap width loops)
    toCheck = nowChecking.neighbours(8, (n) => n[0] > 0 && n[0] < voxels - 1);//gets 8 neighbour points around current point, neighbours between 1 and (voxelwidth -1) get returned
    let foundNew = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < toCheck.length; i++) {//check every neighbour
        let x = toCheck[i][0],
            y = toCheck[i][1],
            index = y * voxels + x;
        if (!checkedVoxels.includes(index)) {
            if (this.voxels[x][y] && (!this.voxels[x][y - 1] || !this.voxels[x + 1][y] || !this.voxels[x - 1][y] || !this.voxels[x][y + 1])) {
                //if the neighbour is a floor voxel, and touches a skyvoxel this neighbour is added to the line
                checkedVoxels.push(index);
                if (foundNew) {//if a valid neighbour is already found, this means there are 2 possible paths from the current point
                    otherPaths.push([x, y]);
                } else {
                    lineGround.push([x / voxels, y / voxels]);
                    nowChecking = [x, y];
                    //valid point gets added to the line and currently explored point get updated
                    foundNew = true;
                }
                if (x >= voxels) done = true;
            }
        } else if (i == toCheck.length - 1 && !foundNew) {
            if (otherPaths.length > 0) {
                nowChecking = otherPaths.pop();
                //if none of the neighbours are correct an alternative path gets explored
                foundNew = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!foundNew || looped++ > voxels * 10) {
        //if it never found a valid neighbour, or it's looped too often break from the whileloop
        console.log('loops: ', looped);
        break;
    }
}

if (lineGround[0][0] !== 0) lineGround.splice(0, 0, [0, lineGround[0][1]]);
if (lineGround[lineGround.length - 1][0] !== 1) lineGround.push([1, lineGround[lineGround.length - 1][1]]);
//x=0 and x=1 have to exist, so if they don't exist yet, add them

return lineGround;
}
```

You can also test it here: [game](http://ruurdbijlsma.com/Tanks/). If you click you remove (set to 0) a few voxels within a radius of where you clicked. Also the line gets recalculated.

I'm stuck on this, because I have no idea why the line stops in some situations. 
All code is [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bwr7Gn0maaNTNFN6b1I0M21MdTQ&usp=sharing). The relevant file is js/Level.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more problems than the one you raised. I played a bit on your site and there are many patterns where things go wrong.

I tried to follow the logic of your code, but got lost in details. So I rewrote most of the code. The main idea is that you should keep record of which direction (slope) you are travelling along the ground in order to know in which order you should look among the neighbours for one that is part of the ground.

Let's say the neighbours are numbered as follows, from 0 to 7:

```
+---+---+---+
| 7 | 0 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
| 6 | * | 2 |
+---+---+---+
| 5 | 4 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
```

The cell marked with `*` is the last cell you found to be on ground level. Now let's say the previous one found was at 6, then the search among the neighbours should start at 7, then 0, 1, 2, ... 5. The first one that is found to be solid, should be the next cell added to ground level.

Another example: if the previous one found was at 4 (we're going upward), then the neighbours should be searched starting at 5, then 6, 7, 0, 1, 2 and 3.

The first neighbour that is found to be solid (ground) is the one you want to add to your ground line. This way you will follow every curve, into "caves", upward or downward, left or right.

Of course, things can still go weird if you start on an island. But I did not attempt to solve that particular case.

I've implemented the above idea in the following version of your method:

```
voxelToLine() {
    let voxels = this.voxels.length, x, y, i;
    // neighbors' relative coordinates listed in clockwise order    
    const neighbor = [ [0,-1], [1,-1], [1,0], [1,1], [0,1], [-1,1], [-1,0], [-1,-1] ];

    for (y = 0; y < voxels; y++) //sets first coordinate for line.
        if (this.voxels[0][y]) break; // found ground, don't look further down
    let lineGround = [[0, y / voxels]];
    let [curX, curY] = [0, y]; //search starts here
    let direction = 0; // upward

    let looped = 0;
    do {// Continues search until right side is located, 
        // or it got stuk (max 10*voxelmap width loops)
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {//check every neighbour, starting at `direction`
            [x, y] = [curX + neighbor[direction][0], curY + neighbor[direction][1]];
            // if we found ground, then pick that cell as the next one on the line
            if (x>=0 && x<voxels && y>=0 && y<voxels && this.voxels[x][y]) break;
            direction = (direction + 1) % 8; // turn clockwise to get next neighbour
        }
        //if it never found a valid neighbour
        if (i === 8) break;
        lineGround.push([x / voxels, y / voxels]);
        // prepare for next round
        [curX, curY] = [x, y];
        direction = (direction + 5) % 8;
    } while (looped++ <= voxels*10 && curX < voxels - 1);

    //x=0 and x=1 have to exist, so if they don't exist yet, add them
    if (lineGround[0][0] !== 0) lineGround.splice(0, 0, [0, lineGround[0][1]]);
    if (lineGround[lineGround.length - 1][0] !== 1) 
        lineGround.push([1, lineGround[lineGround.length - 1][1]]);
    return lineGround;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's skipping over the voxel right below the last legitimate ground voxel because it's already been "checked" (added to the checkedVoxels array).

Interestingly, this would prevent your ground path to ever turn 90 degrees (you'll notice your example picture doesn't have such a voxel pattern).